# drop duplicate rows based on column values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, filter, group-by

| email | date | name | fruits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa@xyz.com | 01-07-2022 12:40:00 | james | kiwi |
| aaa@xyz.com | 01-07-2022 12:10:00 | james | apple |
| aaa@xyz.com | 01-07-2022 12:10:00 | james | orange |
| aaa@xyz.com | 01-07-2022 12:30:00 | james | lemon |
| bbb@xyz.com | 02-07-2022 08:04:00 | clark | apple |
| bbb@xyz.com | 02-07-2022 08:04:00 | clark | orange |
| bbb@xyz.com | 02-07-2022 08:13:00 | clark | kiwi |
| bbb@xyz.com | 02-07-2022 08:28:00 | clark | lemon |
| ccc@xyz.com | 02-06-2022 08:43:00 | beth | kiwi |
| ccc@xyz.com | 02-06-2022 08:48:00 | beth | orange |

In the above dataframe, i want to drop rows associated with name/email-id and retain the earliest time prioritizing 'apple' over 'oranges' in the fruit column i.e., if two rows have the same time stamp and one row has the value 'apple' in the fruit column and the same time stamp but 'orange' in the fruit column, then i want to only retain the row relating to apple.

Output

| email | date | name | completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa@xyz.com | 01-07-2022 12:10:00 | james | apple |
| bbb@xyz.com | 02-07-2022 08:04:00 | clark | apple |
| ccc@xyz.com | 02-06-2022 08:48:00 | beth | orange |

This is what i have tried;

```
res = (
    df.sort_values(['completed', 'date'], 
                   key=lambda col: col.eq('apple') if col.name == 'completed' else col)
      .groupby(['email', 'name'], as_index=False)
      .first()
)
```

Basically, i want to get the earliest 'date' for each name and email. Both 'name' and 'email' columns have duplicate values, the only differentiating factor is the values in the 'date' column. Out of all the values in the 'date' column for a particular person, i want to only retain the earliest date when fruits = ['orange', 'apple'] and drop all the other rows. when there are two rows with the same date but different fruits, i want to retain apple over orange.

Comment: 2nd row in the desired output should be `bbb@xyz.com` ?

Comment: # sort first by df.fruits == 'apple', then by df.date in ascending order; 
# and then select the first row for each group (name, email)
res = (
    df.sort_values(['fruits', 'date'], 
                   key=lambda col: col.eq('apple') if col.name == 'fruits' else col)
      .groupby(['email', 'name'], as_index=False)
      .first()
) this is what i have tried

Comment: such informations should be edited in your question itself and well formatted, not as comment

Comment: What is the sort order of fruits?  Apples>Oranges>everything else or is that particular sort order of fruit? or Apples or Oranges > everything else?

Comment: sort order only applies between apples and oranges, if it is any other fruit, we can drop them. but when the date is the same for apples and oranges then sort order will be apples> oranges

Answer (score 1):

Update using pd.CategoricalDtype:

```
fruit_dtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 'lemn'], ordered=True)
df['fruits']=df['fruits'].astype(fruit_dtype)
df.sort_values(['fruits', 'date'], ascending=[True, True]).drop_duplicates('email')
```

Output:

```
         email                 date   name  fruits
1  aaa@xyz.com  01-07-2022 12:10:00  james   apple
4  bbb@xyz.com  02-07-2022 08:04:00  clark   apple
9  ccc@xyz.com  02-06-2022 08:48:00   beth  orange
```

---

You can try this, create psuedo "sortkey" column, sort and then you can drop after filtering:

```
df.assign(sortkey=df['fruits'].isin(["apple","orange"]))\
  .sort_values('sortkey', ascending=False)\
  .drop_duplicates('email')
```

Output:

```
         email                 date   name  fruits  sortkey
1  aaa@xyz.com  01-07-2022 12:10:00  james   apple     True
4  bbb@xyz.com  02-07-2022 08:04:00  clark   apple     True
9  ccc@xyz.com  02-06-2022 08:48:00   beth  orange     True
```

Comment: This works as long as the row pertaining to 'apple' is above 'orange'. if the order is different, then it does not pick 'apple' over 'orange' for the same date

Comment: @User277883 Okay, then we can create at mapping for psuedo key column or create fruits as a categorical dtype.